# MySQL - Forecast Growth of Family Tree Based on Historical Growth

Tags: mysql

Given a MySQL table that tracks the growth of family tree using Person, BirthDate, and Parent how can I forecast what the family tree will look like in 1, 3, 10, 50 years from now?

Here is the basic table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE FamilyTree (
      PersonID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      Birthdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
      ParentID int NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (PersonID)
    );
```

Here is the historical data to populate the FamilyTree:

```
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (87, '2016-09-01', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (1, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (2, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (3, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (4, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (5, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (6, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (7, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (8, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (9, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (10, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (11, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (12, '2016-09-02', 87)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (79, '2016-09-05', 3)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (80, '2016-09-05', 1)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (81, '2016-09-05', 1)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (82, '2016-09-05', 2)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (83, '2016-09-05', 2)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (84, '2016-09-05', 2)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (85, '2016-09-05', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (86, '2016-09-05', 3)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (88, '2016-09-05', 150)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (89, '2016-09-05', 4)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (90, '2016-09-05', 4)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (93, '2016-09-05', 4)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (94, '2016-09-05', 93)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (95, '2016-09-05', 147)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (96, '2016-09-05', 123)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (97, '2016-09-05', 104)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (98, '2016-09-05', 5)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (99, '2016-09-05', 124)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (100, '2016-09-05', 5)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (101, '2016-09-05', 98)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (102, '2016-09-05', 90)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (103, '2016-09-05', 120)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (104, '2016-09-05', 6)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (105, '2016-09-06', 90)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (107, '2016-09-06', 6)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (108, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (110, '2016-09-06', 116)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (111, '2016-09-06', 6)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (112, '2016-09-06', 111)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (113, '2016-09-06', 110)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (114, '2016-09-06', 90)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (115, '2016-09-06', 7)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (116, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (117, '2016-09-06', 7)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (118, '2016-09-06', 100)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (119, '2016-09-06', 7)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (120, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (121, '2016-09-06', 110)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (122, '2016-09-06', 7)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (123, '2016-09-06', 130)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (124, '2016-09-06', 8)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (125, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (126, '2016-09-06', 99)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (127, '2016-09-06', 8)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (128, '2016-09-06', 122)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (129, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (130, '2016-09-06', 1)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (131, '2016-09-06', 124)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (132, '2016-09-06', 8)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (133, '2016-09-06', 9)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (134, '2016-09-06', 94)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (135, '2016-09-06', 9)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (136, '2016-09-06', 90)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (137, '2016-09-06', 1344)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (138, '2016-09-06', 93)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (139, '2016-09-06', 128)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (140, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (141, '2016-09-06', 136)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (142, '2016-09-06', 9)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (143, '2016-09-06', 128)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (144, '2016-09-06', 86)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (145, '2016-09-06', 146)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (146, '2016-09-06', 10)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (147, '2016-09-06', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (148, '2016-09-06', 10)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (149, '2016-09-06', 99)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (150, '2016-09-06', 3)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (151, '2016-09-06', 99)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (152, '2016-09-06', 129)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (153, '2016-09-07', 190)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (154, '2016-09-07', 151)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (155, '2016-09-07', 119)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (156, '2016-09-07', 93)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (157, '2016-09-07', 151)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (158, '2016-09-07', 122)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (159, '2016-09-07', 147)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (160, '2016-09-07', 11)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (161, '2016-09-07', 146)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (162, '2016-09-07', 118)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (163, '2016-09-07', 99)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (164, '2016-09-07', 146)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (165, '2016-09-07', 151)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (166, '2016-09-07', 145)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (169, '2016-09-07', 121)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (170, '2016-09-07', 146)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (171, '2016-09-07', 125)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (172, '2016-09-07', 165)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (173, '2016-09-07', 145)
    INSERT INTO FamilyTree (PersonID, Birthdate, ParentID) VALUES (174, '2016-09-07', 161)
```

Comment: Do you want to estimate the size of the database table? Or what do you mean by "forecast"?

Comment: I want to expand the People in the table (children) to forecast what the family tree will look like in the future based on the current tree. Basically, answer the question, "Given this group of parent/children and when the children were born what will this family tree expand to in 1 year?"